# One attribute for several views in layout XML (Avoiding repetitive code)

Tags: android, xml

I have the following layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"> // The layout_gravity doesn't seem to affect 
                                     // the button Views 
                                     // (I guess this is the wrong way to do it)

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Genre2"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I make a single general attribute configuration e.g. **android:layout_gravity="center"** for all my Button Views?

Comment: can u show how you want to display in xml??

Comment: pls describe how ur xml should look like??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below line

```
android:gravity="center"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap common attributes for a certain View under a style.

Create a styles.xml file in your values folder, and just declare the styles:

```
<style name="list_item_title">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then, on your TextView (or Button, or whatever View...):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    style="@style/list_item_title" />
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `android:gravity="center"` instead of   `android:layout_gravity="center"`

or you can try `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your buttons xml